# "I need required a bean of type" Error : Spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot

I get an error when I try to execute SpringBoot. because I need a " bean ", I don't understand why I get this, I have all annotations

```
17-09-2018 12:24:53.905 [restartedMain] WARN  o.s.b.c.e.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'parameterController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'pgService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'parameterServiceImp': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'pgRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'es.my.repository.ParameterRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

With more error :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

```
Description:

Field pgRepository in es.service.ParameterServiceImp required a bean of type 'es.repository.ParameterRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'es.repository.ParameterRepository' in your configuration.
```

I have in my controller -> with @Autowired

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = { "/param" })
@CrossOrigin
public class ParameterController {

    @Autowired
    ParameterService pgService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/get", produces = 
    MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public List<Parameter> getAllParameters() {
        List<Parameter> list = pgService.selectAll();
        return list;
    }
```

In my service -> I don't use annotations

```
public interface ParameterService {
    public List<Parameter> selectAll();
}
```

Imple-> I use Service and Autowired

```
@Service
public class ParameterServiceImp implements ParameterService {
    @Autowired
    ParameterRepository pgRepository;

    public List<Parameter> selectAll() {
        return pgRepository.findAll());
    }
}
```

Repository -> Here , I have querys.

```
public interface ParameterRepository extends CrudRepository<Parameter, String> {
}
```

Model ->
My POJO

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Parameter")
public class Parameter {

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

// getters setters and construct

}
```

I have @Entity , @Service , @Autowired but I get an error

[image]

Comment: Have you put @Repository on your repository interface? How is your package tree structure? Make sure it is picked up by component scan.

Comment: @Repository .. nothing.

Comment: Share your directory structure also

Comment: already, I upload  imagen

Comment: Your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class should be in the top level package `es` ( and whatever you removed). I suspect you have that in some kind of sub packages judging by the fact that you use a technical separation rather then function separation. Also the fact that you get this error combined with a config package scares me as you probably are trying to out-smart Spring Boot with some things disabling auto-configuration.

Comment: this proyect run with DynamoDB, but When I change a Mysql .... boom ... :( I changed the annotations from DynamoDB a Mysql ...

Comment: I think there is something wrong about your folder structure, please make sure that all your files are in the right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `@SpringBootApplication` with no `basePackage` specified, it will default to the current package. Just like you add `@ComponentScan` and `@EnableJpaRepositories` with no base package.

If you have set a different package to `@SpringBootApplication` make sure you also add `@EnableJpaRepositories` with proper basePackage. Repositories won't be recognized only by `@ComponentScan`(or declaring them as beans by any other ways explicitly or implicitly).

Answer (score 0):

is a.some.package package for your @SpingbootApplication?
other wise you need to add component scan annotation for your base package that is a.some.package

Comment: If you use Springboot you don't need to add component scan.

Comment: already, I upload  imagen, please @Ravenloup, remove the name the my package.

Comment: Remove package scan for repository only @EnableJpaRepositories is enough
 and make sure package structure is like below 
a.b
a.b.c
a.b.r
or
add @ComponentScan("a.b.*")

Comment: nothing the nothing ... I changed imports but nothing... I need help :(

Comment: can you share pom, app.java and application.properties, I also faced this issue but it fixed by package structure or by component scan, 
Once I faced it because I added basepackage for repositories .....

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the next annotation.

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"<repository-package-here>"})
```

Comment: nothing, also, I have in my Application @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"es.*"})